# Error in updating mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, security, phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE 
  `code_library_questions` 
SET 
  `answer` = 'value' 
WHERE 
  `sn` = 2;
```

Its working fine when value is some text. But whenever value include some codes of C or C++, it gives following error message

> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/tbl_replace.php on this server.

why it is happening???

Comment: Please give us an example of what kinds of values you are passing in `value` and _how_ you are passing them.   Most likely you need to properly escape quotes.

Comment: And the error message implies a broken installation of `phpmyadmin` rather than a MySQL error. Moreover, most likely the value isn't escaped, which generates invalid code.

Comment: I need to save C and C++ codes in my database.

Comment: Here value is a C or C++ code like int main() { for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { cout<<i; } return 0;}

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the ModSecurity rules are detecting the code that is inserted as a possible SQL injection.  Check the /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.log file to see what exactly it is complaining about.  You may have to change the rules but if you do please make sure your MySQLAdmin is otherwise secured for access.

Comment: Thanks a lot Turnkey..In my project I need to save C and C++ codes in my database to display it in the PHP pages. What is the best way to do so without compromising with the security of the database?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the logs to see exactly what is being rejected.  You might be able to htmlencode some of the inputs (if it is complaining about > or <).